# How do I set post permalink(or a slug)?

Tags: python, wordpress

How can I use python to set the value of a permalink on a wordpress post?

Slug will work too, but permalink would be better(I want to set it to a different domain).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with WordPress rest API

http://wp-api.org/

https://github.com/stylight/python-wordpress-json